# Token Authentication in Dart

Tags: authentication, authorization, dart

After reading James Wards artice on [Securing Single Page Apps and REST Services](http://www.jamesward.com/2013/05/13/securing-single-page-apps-and-rest-services), I'd very much like to implement this in Dart. However I have found so few examples in Dart on the topic of authentication. I'm particularly interested implementing steps 6 - 9 from the article:

- The server validates the login information and creates an
  authentication token for the user
- The server sets the authentication
  token in a cookie and returns it to the JavaScript application
- The JavaScript application makes a request for some protected data,
  sending the authentication token in a custom header
- The server validates the token and then returns the data

Can someone provide a simple client/server example of this in Dart. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you assuming Dart running on both client and server?

Comment: Yes, both client and server are running Dart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest the easiest thing to do is to use the Google OAuth2 pub package with Dart on the server to generate a token as described in this [tutorial](http://blog.dartwatch.com/2013/04/sign-in-with-google-using-google-oauth2.html).

If you want to use cookies to store the token as James suggests, you can do so like this:

```dart
document.cookie = "token=TOKEN;max-age=${60*60*24*7*4}";
```

You read the cookie like this:

```dart
var token = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)token\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
```

And send it back in a custom header like this:

```dart
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.open("Get", "www.server.com");
req.setRequestHeader("custom-token-header", token);
```

Then you can validate the token as described in the tutorial.

Comment: Good tip on the OAuth2, going to look more into it.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project!

Comment: The tutorial link has gone bad.  Here's a web archive link to the same page: http://web.archive.org/web/20150810232156/http://blog.dartwatch.com/2013/04/sign-in-with-google-using-google-oauth2.html